# Django form bringing unselected data

Tags: django, forms

Am creating a django form that enables me enter student marks but it works best for the start and it then brings students I didn't select .
The project that collects student marks but am trying to make a form that inputs marks after selecting the students on one form but this works well before I enter any marks but it then brings all the students whose marks I've already entered plus those I select for new entries.

In my views.py I have that

```
@login_required
def create_result(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":

        # after visiting the second page
        if "finish" in request.POST:
            form = CreateResults(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                subjects = form.cleaned_data["subjects"]
                session = form.cleaned_data["session"]
                term = form.cleaned_data["term"]
                students = request.POST["students"]
                results = []
                for student in students.split(","):
                    stu = Student.objects.get(pk=student)
                    if stu.current_class:
                        for subject in subjects:
                            check = Result.objects.filter(
                                session=session,
                                term=term,
                                current_class=stu.current_class,
                                subject=subject,
                                student=stu,
                            ).first()
                            if not check:
                                results.append(
                                    Result(
                                        session=session,
                                        term=term,
                                        current_class=stu.current_class,
                                        subject=subject,
                                        student=stu,
                                    )
                                )

                Result.objects.bulk_create(results)
                return redirect("Results:new-results")

        # after choosing students
        id_list = request.POST.getlist("students")
        if id_list:
            form = CreateResults(
                initial={
                    "session": request.current_session,
                    "term": request.current_term,
                }
            )
            studentlist = ",".join(id_list)
            return render(
                request,
                "Results/resultsentry1.html",
                {"students": studentlist, "form": form, "count": len(id_list)},
            )
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "You didnt select any student.")
    return render(request, "Results/resultsentry.html", {"students": students})


@login_required
def New_result(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Fill_result(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Results successfully created")
            return redirect("Results:Resultsview")
    else:
        results = Result.objects.filter(
          
        )
        form = Fill_result(queryset=results)
    return render(request, "Results/fill_results1.html", {"formset": form})**
```

}
In my html form

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}
Update Results
{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<br>
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formset.management_form}}

  <table id="studenttable" class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
       
        <th>Exam Score</th>
       
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Class</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for form in formset %}
      {{ form.id}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{forloop.counter }}</td>
          <td>{{form.instance.student }}</td>
          <td>{{form.instance.subject}}</td>
          
          <td style="width: 10%;">{{form.exam_score | add_class:"form-control form-control-sm"}}</td>
          
          <td>{{form.DELETE}}</td>
          <td>{{form.instance.current_class}}</td>

        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I thought it could help me but it failed.